# Text inside divs wrapping on top of each other when browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Currently, I have a nav bar that contains divs, and inside of the divs there's text. Unfortunately, when the browser resizes it causes the text to shift and eventually they are all warped on each other.
Check out the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6jvxLr4k/4/

html

```
<nav id= 'headWrap' class="wrapFix">  <div id= "nameCont"> Tupac Shakur
</div>

<div class="link" id="postOne"> Yo! </div>

<div class="link" id="postTwo"> About </div> 


<div class="link" id="postThree"> GitHub </div> 
<div class="link" id= "postFour"> Contact  </div> 






</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#nameCont {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:5%;
}
#postOne {
    position: absolute;
    right:40%;
    top:0;
}
#postTwo {
    position: absolute;
    right:20%;
    top:0;
}
#postThree {
    position: absolute;
    right:10%;
    top:0;
}
#postFour {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: What behavior would you like it to have?  You probably should absolutely position the elements...depending on how you want to layout the menu you could simply float the items and give them specific widths/padding/margins to get your spacing...then if you want it to react differently based on the browser size you'd want to include media queries.

Comment: That is expected behaviour. Try giving your `nav` a `min-width`.

Comment: You probably need to change the techniques you are using to position that text. [Here is an example I made for you that might give you a head start](http://jsbin.com/fezeye/2/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` will do that. Just give the elements inside `.wrapFix` a percentage width to position them.

Here is the updated css https://jsfiddle.net/6jvxLr4k/7/